# How to change oracle Date from mm/dd/yyyy formate into MON DD YYYY formate

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

i have table having regular date formate

Table 1

```
ID   Date
123  08/01/2015
456  09/01/2015
```

but I need to see this date in this format.

```
ID   Date    
123  AUG 01 2015    
456  SEP 01 2015
```

Comment: A DATE column doesn't have a format; it has an internal representation which is converted to a readable value for display, using your NLS_DATE_FORMAT if you don't specify your own format to use. Hopefully it is actually a DATE, and you aren't storing dates as strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `to_char()` to format the date:

```
select id, to_char(date, 'MON DD YYYY') 
from the_table;
```

More details about to_char() can be found in the manual:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions200.htm#SQLRF06129